# How Really Effective are the Measures of Psychological Tests in Jobs Interviews and Worker Performance After Inside the Workplace

Tags: statistics, test, io-psychology

Hello I work doing smalls gig with datasets and also sometimes I create for myself some infographics and data-visualizations of interesting topics for me. for example football, cryptos, virus, etc.

I want to do a data visualization or infographic. Testing my curious hypothesis about how effective are the psycological test proposals in research/theory and his real aplications in job selecting. There are some research about that? Is really a scientific fact, can psychologics predict the future performance of a worker? Do you have datasets related to measure this variables in various workers?

Comment: These tests are typically quite poor at predicting. Do you have a particular test and application in mind?

Comment: maybe we can test the best predictor of various psicological test like an metanalysis.